# Linking Data directory containg csv files to CLion project

Tags: c++, csv, file, cmake, clion

How can I use a directory that contains .csv files (containing some data) inside the program? I think I need to configure the cmake but I don't know how to do it.

I tried adding folder to cmake and hoping that it would run it program could not access that files inside the folder.

Comment: Define "use". What are you doing with them?

Comment: If you have local csv files that you need your program to read you might need to write CMake code that copy those files next to the executable. That can be done with a custom target

Comment: Can't you modify your code to have it change the current working directory to the one containing the csv files? Or use a full path to the csv files?